# OwnsOne with nullable principal key errors

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to configure an entity that can optionally belong to a group, but am getting an error that I think is caused by the key being nullable. I am using EF core 5

The main parent entity is configured as

```
public class Option 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

and a group is configured as

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping is configured as

```
builder.Entity<Option>().OwnsOne(o => o.Group, b =>
{
    b.WithOwner().HasPrincipalKey(o => o.GroupId).HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
});
```

However, this results in the error `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.` It seems to be an issue with a nullable principal key. Am I configuring this relationship wrong, or is optional owned entities just not a scenario EF supports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I configuring this relationship wrong, or is optional owned entities just not a scenario EF supports?

The later. The owner cannot be optional. It is required. That's essentially what distinguishes owned entity types from the regular (non owned) ones as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities):

> Owned entities are essentially a part of the owner and cannot exist without it

If you want optional principal, then configure the dependent as regular entity having 0 or 1 (optional one-to-one) relationship with the principal. This also would require them to have their own table, since they cannot share the same table (a.k.a.  [table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting)) because it also requires the primary (principal) entity to exists, and only dependent(s) could be optional.